# Can I return Components inside of a function's callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, mern

I am hoping to mount a component class  inside of a map iteration of an array. Because the array went through two transformations, I have two functions for handling this transformation but the final components aren't being mounted.

Articles are presented in a blog style by day. With GraphQL I get a list of all the days an article was published {listDates()}. Then, I need to get just the unique dates and ensure they are in reverse order {sortDates()}. With this array, I need to past the individual dates to their own  component where another query takes place to render all the articles for that day.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import PostsDay from "./postsDay";
var dateFormat = require("dateformat");
var array = require("lodash/array");
var collection = require("lodash/collection");

 const getDatesQuery = gql`
   {
     posts(where: { status: "published" }) {
        published
     }
    }
  `;

 class PostsFeed extends Component {
   sortDates = allDates => {
     let uniqueSortedDates = array.reverse(
       array.uniq(collection.sortBy(allDates))
     );

      uniqueSortedDates.map((d, index) => {
        console.log("should be posting", d);
        return <PostsDay key={index} artDate={d} />;
      });
    };
    listDates = (data, allDates, sortDates) => {
      data.posts.forEach(post => {
        allDates.push(dateFormat(post.published, "yyyy-mm-dd"));
     });
sortDates(allDates);
    };
   render() {
     let data = this.props.data;
let allDates = [];

if (data.loading) {
  return "Loading...";
} else {
  return <div>{this.listDates(data, allDates, this.sortDates)} . 
 </div>;
     }
    }
  }

  export default graphql(getDatesQuery)(
    withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(PostsFeed)
   );
```

I expect for all my  components to be loaded. The console reads the following:

```
 should be posting 2017-11-14
 should be posting 2017-11-13
 should be posting 2017-11-11
 should be posting 2017-11-04
 ...
```

so we're getting into the {sortDates()} function but not rendering the component. What don't I understand. Please help. Thank you, all.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo. You forgot the `return` statement in the `listDates` function.

Comment: @Quentin, I don't want to return anything from `listDates`. It's actuating the function `sortDates` where the return statement is.

Comment: `<div>{this.listDates(data, allDates, this.sortDates)} </div>` — You're inserting the return value of `listDates` into your DOM, not the return value of `sortDates`

Comment: `sortDates` doesn't have a `return` statement either. (No, the one in the anonymous function you pass to `map` doesn't count, that's a different function).

Comment: @Quentin, thank you for your help in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

The insight from @Quentin helped a lot. I was able to clean up the code and get everything working properly.

```
class PostsFeed extends Component {
  state = {
    uniqueSortedDates: []
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (!data.loading && data.posts !== prevProps.data.posts) {
      this.listDays(data);
    }
  }

  listDays = data => {
    let allDates = [];
    data.posts.forEach(post => {
      allDates.push(dateFormat(post.published, "yyyy-mm-dd"));
    });
    const uniqueSortedDates = array.reverse(
      array.uniq(collection.sortBy(allDates))
    );
    this.setState({ uniqueSortedDates: uniqueSortedDates });
  };

  render() {
    const { uniqueSortedDates } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {uniqueSortedDates.slice(0, 5).map(date => {
          return <PostsDay key={date} artDate={date} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```